# How to convert XML file to binary file

Tags: c#, xml, binary

How could I convert XML file to Binary file(BXML) for hiding its contents to distribute?

I have used CryptoBinary/DecrytBinary for hiding XML file.
But, I'd like to convert XML file to Binary file directly.

```
    ///-----------------------------------------------------------------
    /// Using part
    private void GetBookInfo()
    {
        //Books XML file
        Utility.XmlDeSerializer<CBooks>(ref Uinst, Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Book.xml");
        // Books Binary file
        string binXmlString = Utility.ReadCryptoBinaryFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Book.bin");
        Utility.XmlStringToObject<CBooks>(ref Uinst, binXmlString);
    }

    private void SetBookInfo()
    {
        // Books XML file
        Utility.XmlSerializer<CBooks>(Uinst, Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Book.xml");
        //For test. for Books Binary file
        string binXmlString = Utility.ObjectToXmlString<CBooks>(Uinst);
        Utility.WriteCryptoBinaryFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Book.bin", binXmlString);
    }




    ///-----------------------------------------------------------------
    /// Utility part
    public static void XmlDeSerializer<T>(ref T t, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());
            using (StreamReader Rstream = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                t = (T)serializer.Deserialize(Rstream);
                Rstream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to create object from xml string\r\n{0}", ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

    public static string ReadCryptoBinaryFile(string path)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

            cryptic.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Value.sKey);
            cryptic.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Value.sIV);

            CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
                cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            //reader = new StreamReader(crStream);
            //rreturn reader.ReadToEnd();
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(crStream);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length));
        }
        #region
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new IOException(string.Format("Message: {0}", ex));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            if (stream != null)
            {
                /*stream.Flush(); */
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
    public static void XmlStringToObject<T>(ref T obj, string xmlString)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(StringToBytes(xmlString, Encoding.UTF8));
            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
            obj = (T)xs.Deserialize(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to " + "create object from xml string", ex);
        }
    }
    public static void XmlSerializer<T>(T obj, string path)
    {
        try
        {                
            XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            using (StreamWriter Wstream = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                xmlserializer.Serialize(Wstream, obj);
                Wstream.Flush(); Wstream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to create xml file from object\r\n{0}", ex);
        }
    }

    public static string ObjectToXmlString<T>(T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            string xmlString = null;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
            xs.Serialize(xtw, obj);
            ms = (MemoryStream)xtw.BaseStream;
            //xtw.WriteBinHex(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
            xmlString = BytesToString(ms.ToArray(), Encoding.UTF8); 
            return xmlString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to " + "create xml string from object", ex);
        }
    }

    public static void WriteCryptoBinaryFile(string path, string data)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;
        CryptoStream crStream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

            cryptic.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Value.sKey);
            cryptic.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Value.sIV);

            crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
               cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            //byte[] bt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            //crStream.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(crStream);
            bw.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        }
        #region
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new IOException(string.Format("Message: {0}", ex));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (crStream != null)
            {
                crStream.Flush(); crStream.Close();
            }
            if (stream != null)
            {
                /*stream.Flush(); */
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve in more detail and provide more details on the code sample and highlight the portions that are not working as desired?

Comment: Something like this? https://wbxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Stratus3D while i think the OP has fallen into xy problem, the question is distinct enough - binary xml is a standard (in fact,  several standards, e.g. http://www.w3.org/TR/wbxml/)

Comment: In the most pure sense, _all_ files are "binary". Even text like XML has to be represented as binary information when stored in a computer. Perhaps you mean to obfuscate the data somehow. One trivial way to do that is simply to compress it, e.g. with `GzipStream`. If you are trying to secure it, .NET has encryption features such as those found in `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace. Though note that if a user has access to the program that encrypts the file, they can decrypt the file. As stated, your question is current too vague, and too broad.